# Permission denied when using file.remove in R

Tags: r

I'm trying to remove a file from a directory in my R code and I'm getting this error..

> cannot remove file //just//an//address//temp//CPD2.JPG, reason 'Permission denied'

I'm using `file.remove`.Is there a reason why I would see this error?

Comment: Apart from the obvious writing-rights conflict, this might also be caused by security settings of your computer. Because if you're doing this over a network, the attempt will be seen as an inbound connection, and on my computer my firewall will block that. Unless I use the classic 127.0.0.1 address to refer to my computer, as I have added exceptions for that.

Comment: you probably have the file opened via another `program.exe`

Comment: OK - so I physically tried myself on the file and it won't let me delete it...? I have nothing else open at all....just explorer..?                              the action cannot be completed because the file is open in system

Answer (score 1):

Do you have rights to delete an image? You can check it with `right clicking on it -> Properties` and looking at the `Attributes`. Be sure that `Read-only` is turned off.

edit: also, you probably meant `file.remove` in the question.